# Why cursorMark and timeAllowed cannot be used together?

Tags: solr, solrj

When both cursorMark and timeAllowed are used in a solr query, the server returns an error: Can not search using both cursorMark and timeAllowed.

Why does it happen? 
Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that if the timeAllowed triggered, the nextCursorMark value would not make any sense. So instead of having the search potentially return a borked value, Solr refuses to perform a cursorMark search when timeAllowed is present.

[Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5463?focusedCommentId=13859803&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13859803)